# Displaying a WEBM in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get a webm video to play on a single page website i'm developing.

For some reason it's not displaying or playing properly. I'm using Django with Python as a backend and just simple HTML with Bootstrap as a front end.

Really appreciate the help.

Here's the code.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 nopadding full-screen force-full-screen dark videoplay-on-hover">
                <div class="vertical-middle ignore-header center">
                    <h2 class="nobottommargin ls1 font-body">different.</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="video-wrap">
                    <video id="slide-video" poster="{% static 'img/videos/1.jpg'%}" preload="auto" loop muted>
                        <source src="{% static 'img/videos/1.webm' %}" type='video/webm' />
                        <source src="{% static 'img/videos/1.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4' />
                    </video>
                    <div class="video-overlay" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I use the {% static ...%} for images it works fine. I don't really understand why it would be different for webm or mp4 type files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved. Basically I had not placed the associated files in the right folder. So there was no issue with Django or Python - Just a simple error in file placement.